# nodemon app crashed when run this 'npm run test-watch'

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, nodemon

In my package.json file I write this run nodemon:
`"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha server/**/*.test.js",
    "test-watch": "nodemon --exec 'npm test'"
  },`
And this error showed in terminal:

```
> node-todo-api@1.0.0 test-watch D:\nodepractice\node-todo-api
> nodemon --exec 'npm test'

[nodemon] 1.12.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `'npm test'`
''npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

How to resolve this problem, I want to use nodemon.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you manually run npm test?

Comment: when i run this npm test

    > node-todo-api@1.0.0 test D:\nodepractice\node-todo-api
    > mocha server/**/*.test.js

    Warning: Could not find any test files matching pattern: 
    server/**/*.test.js
    No test files found
    npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details. @jmcgui05

Comment: Can you update the above code to include the full package.json, or at least where the script lies in there?

Comment: updated but still same output

Comment: want to see my test file script ??@jmcgui05

Comment: The error you get when manually running npm test suggest that the test dir is not located where it should be. The error you get when nodemon fails on npm test suggests that npm is not installed correctly globally, or that nodemon does not have access to it.

Comment: npm test command works for me but nodemon does not work at all I installed it globally and locally

Comment: Check where nodemon is installed. If it is installed in the global node modules, it should have access to npm. Thats if npm is installed correctly in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of putting in single quotes why don't you put in double quotes by escaping them.

Try this:

```
"test-watch":"nodemon --exec \"npm test\""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Windows try to remove the single quotes after the exec command:

```
"test-watch": "nodemon --exec npm test"
```

Comment: Please explain what this command does, and\or why it should solve the problem